# Looking for website for organising private tournaments with swiss system?

Tags: software, tournament, online-chess

Do you know any website for organising online chess tournaments with swiss pairing method ? I know lichess.org but they don't support it anymore :/

Answer (score 2):

The related question [How to organize a chess tournament](https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-to-organize-a-chess-tournament) appears to have several suggestions; I'm not personally familiar with any of them, but most of the links seem to still be active.

Comment: http://www.chessmoon.com/  is the only possible option for me, but they don't support creating private tournaments, and the number of players is limited to only 12 :/

Answer (score 0):

You can do it on [playchess.com](http://playchess.com) in the 'tournaments room'.

Comment: is anyone authorized to do so ? or there are some conditions.. ?

Comment: As far as I remember, you need to be a *Bishop* rank user, which is not hard to achieve(again as far as I remember, 30 days of login grants you *Bishop* rank).

Answer (score -1):

You can try [chess.com](http://chess.com), but you must be a premium user to create a tournament.