# What are some of the chess sites that allow Round Robin or Swiss Tournament to be organized?

Tags: tournament, online

I have been experimenting with the Team feature and tournament features in Lichess, but I just learned that it's not possible to have swiss, round robin or manual pairing in Lichess. A couple of months ago, I organized a rapid league in my chess club and it went really well, but after a few months, we stopped it due to financial problems. There were three leagues, A, B and C with one round-robin tournament each month (For A and B) while C had a swiss tournament. After each tournament, the top and bottom two shift groups and the winners of the Swiss get a place in B group. Learned so much from running the league. Recently I checked Lichess and fell in love with the beautiful interface (but sad at the lack of features for Swiss/RR tournaments), so, I wanted to ask if there's a good place to organize such a league online? I checked chess.com but it wants me to pay. Still researching!

Comment: Have you seen this question asked previously? Does it answer your question? https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/468/how-to-organize-a-chess-tournament

Comment: lichess has swiss, but still lacks round robin capability.  I too am looking for round robin format.  Chess.com might have it.  I read the "daily tournament" is a round robin, and you can make your own, but you have to be a paying member which I am not.

Answer (score 0):

This is an online option:

https://chess.swips.eu/

But beware that the free version has the following limitations: up to 20 players in only one category, up to 5 rounds with only one tiebreak method.

Comment: this appears to be for over-the-board tournaments, not online playing sites.